# Is there ramdrive on AWS EC2 instance by default?

Tags: amazon-ec2, tmpfs, ramdisk

I found my `df` command says the following:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            31428656        0  31428656   0% /dev
tmpfs            6288016     9136   6278880   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      60923900 21887760  39019756  36% /
tmpfs           31440072        0  31440072   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           31440072        0  31440072   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            6288016        0   6288016   0% /run/user/1000
```

Is any of `tmpfs` a ramdrive? Can I just use `/dev/shm` for my program temp-file storage? Is this ramdrive (very fast)?

Comment: In general temp file storage, if you have enough ram, will stay in the disk cache buffer so already be "very fast" but if you really want to you could use `/dev/shm` to force it to stay there...

Answer (score 2):

You could test the speed of the /dev/shm path by dd'ing some data into it:

```
[ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-x ~]$ dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/shm/test bs=1 count=1M
22+1048554 records in
22+1048554 records out
7514873 bytes (7.5 MB) copied, 89.3415 s, 84.1 kB/s
```

Comment: I wasn't able to see the end of this command.

Comment: Do you mean the end of the `dd` command? or the result in your instance?

Comment: I ran command and it ran forever.

Comment: exactly this command `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/shm/test bs=1M count=1024`on my instance runs for 0.4 seconds creating a `/dev/shm/test` that is 37k in size

Comment: Doesn't `bs=1M count=1024` imply `1GB` in total?

Comment: thats right, it should be but isn't, my instance only has 500M free space but I can only create a ~40k file. unfortunately I haven't looked much deeper into this yet.

Comment: Ahh I see, `M` goes on count size according to manpage. I did a much `bs=10 count =10M` and I ended up with it finishing in about the correct ~8MB in 90 Seconds. quite slow.